# @Html.ActionLink, @Url.Action do not work in asp.net core razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to use the @Html.ActionLink and @Url.Action in my razor pages.

for this I have the following code in my view

```
<div Id="SetLanguageUrl" value="@Url.Action("SetLanguage", "Language")"></div>
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "SetLanguage", "Language")
```

I do not get an error on this, but both do not resolve the url as can be seen in the browser development tools screenshot.

[image: browser developer tools screenshot]

Anybody know what I could be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this has been very frustrating but here is the solution.

In Startup.cs - configure I had the following:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

When I change this to:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

It seems to work.

Comment: You can change it to  `endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();`, if you dont need to modify the default route.

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed work and is more concise.

Comment: Mark your "answer" as Answer, will help others if they have the same Question.